# maven surefire logging (NetBeans)

Tags: maven, netbeans, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a maven project with 1 JUnit5 test using mvn and surefire.  I have`spring-boot-starter-logging` (so really logback) for logging and I have a `logback-test.xml` in `src/test/resources`.  When I right click and hit "Test", logging works as expected.

If, on the other hand, I right click on a singular unit test class and hit "Debug Test File" the logging doesn't engage and I see no log statements.  There seems to be a discrepancy with how the classpaths are set between the 2 methods.  Anything I'm missing?  I really need to be able to debug tests with logging enabled.

Thanks